# How to use Multi line DOTALL with charater exception in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have to find multi line pattern in python. So I am using DOTALL from regex but It is finding more than what I need.

sample file:

```
if(condition_1)
{
....
some text
some text

if ((condition_1== condition_2)   ||
                 (condition_3== condition_4) ||
           (condition_6== condition_5)  ||
     (condition_7== condition_8)   ) // XYZ_variable
{
...
```

My python regex follows

```
re.compile(r'(if\s*?\()(.*?)(\/\/\s*?)(XYZ_variable)', re.DOTALL)
```

this is finding from first if conditions until XYZ_variable but I need only the second if condition where is XYZ_variable is present.

so I changed my regex as follows which is not working

```
re.compile(r'(if\s*?\()([^\{].*?)(\/\/\s*?)(XYZ_variable)', re.DOTALL)
```

My final output shall be like

```
if(condition_1)
    {
    ....
    some text
    some text

    if (((condition_1== condition_2)   ||
                     (condition_3== condition_4) ||
               (condition_6== condition_5)  ||
         (condition_7== condition_8)   ) || XYZ_variable )
    {
    ...
```

but my regex does something like this

```
if ((condition_1)
        {
        ....
        some text
        some text

        if ((condition_1== condition_2)   ||
                         (condition_3== condition_4) ||
                   (condition_6== condition_5)  ||
             (condition_7== condition_8)   ) || XYZ_variable )
        {
        ...
```

Comment: is there a possibility of reverse regex match that i find XYZ_variable first and then go backward until i find the first if condition ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse a programming language. Are you sure you don't want to use an actual parser instead? Then you'd be able to work with it as a syntax tree.

Comment: @jpmc26 this reverse regex i want to try just that i could find an answer to my question here. I also tried the negative lookbehind and positive lookbehind that they are not doing the multiline lookbehind

Comment: If your `if`s always appear as first on a line, use `re.findall(r'(?m)^\s*(if\s*\()(.*(?:\n(?!\s*if\s*\().*)*)//\s*(XYZ_variable)', text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I made small trick to find all if conditions and search each find for this regex but my problem started how could i write it back to the same file

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no My actual problem is this one. since I could not find solution for this one. I tried to bring all my if condition as single line so i could avoid this questions problem

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?m)^(\s*if\s*)(\(.*(?:\n(?!\s*if\s*\().*)*)//\s*(\w+)', r'\1(\2 || \3)', s)`? See https://rextester.com/QSYWTB71824 and https://regex101.com/r/eDvGHp/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my question. Main idea was not converting the if condition as single line.

Comment: See https://rextester.com/QSYWTB71824 and https://regex101.com/r/eDvGHp/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190486/discussion-between-fastlearner-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?m)^(\s*if\s*)(\(.*(?:\n(?!\s*if\s*\().*)*)//\s*(\w+)\s*$', r'\1(\2 || \3)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eDvGHp/2/).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.M` flag
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\s*if\s*)` - Group 1: `if` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\(.*(?:\n(?!\s*if\s*\().*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\s*if\s*\().*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\n(?!\s*if\s*\()` - a newline, LF, that is not followed with `if` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and then followed with `(`
    - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `//\s*` - `//` and 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 3: 1 or more word chars
- `\s*$` - 0+ whitespaces and end of line.

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/XPON48451):

```
import re
s = """if(condition_1)
{
....
some text
some text

if ((condition_1== condition_2)   ||
                 (condition_3== condition_4) ||
           (condition_6== condition_5)  ||
     (condition_7== condition_8)   ) // XYZ_variable
{
..."""
print( re.sub(r'(?m)^(\s*if\s*)(\(.*(?:\n(?!\s*if\s*\().*)*)//\s*(\w+)\s*$', r'\1(\2 || \3)', s) )
```

Output:

```
if(condition_1)
{
....
some text
some text

if (((condition_1== condition_2)   ||
                 (condition_3== condition_4) ||
           (condition_6== condition_5)  ||
     (condition_7== condition_8)   )  || XYZ_variable)
{
...
```

Comment: Nicely explained. I have tried also lookbehind. So is it possible to try look behind with multiline ? for the same question.

Comment: @fastlearner No idea what lookbehind you are talking about. You do not need a lookbehind here.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression captures the first pattern matched. That is why it always takes starting from the first `if`.

Consider the following minimal example, where the non-greedy `?` does not modify the output:

```
>>> re.compile(r"if(.*?)XYZ").search("if a if b if c XYZ").group(1)
' a if b if c '
```

But there, the non-greedy `?` does modify the output:

```
>>> re.compile(r"if(.*?)XYZ").search("if a XYZ if b if c XYZ").group(1)
' a '
```

The non-greedy `?` operates only on the right side of the search.

Comment: but in this case c is not found separate, it shall be found like if b if c instead of just c