# convert many lines if conditions as single line using regex python in a c file

Tags: python, regex

I have a c file where i need to convert multiline if conditions to single line in the same file. It may sound it is not necessary to do it but I will need it as single line since i want add or delete a condition from that if condition later on using regx python as well.

I could use `re.findall` from a pattern `re.compile(r'if\s*?\(.*?\{', re.DOTALL)`to match all conditions and convert as single line in the list but I could not put this back to same file.

from c file

```
   if ((condition_1 == condition_2) ||
       (condition_3 == condition_4) ||
       (condition_6 == condition_5) ||
       (condition_7 == condition_8) ) // XYZ_variable
   {
      some text
      if((condition_1 == condition_2) ||
         (condition_3 == condition_4))
      {
        some texts..

        if (condition)
        {
           some texts
```

as single line in the same c file.

Comment: Will replace work? [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/jp9qq5/1) Let me know if it works.

Comment: I need to just convert the if conditions from whole c file

Comment: *Whatever* modification you make, you cannot modify the file in place (i.e. "put this back to same file") if the modified text has different length than the original.  For such substantial changes as you have in mind, it would probably be a bad idea to attempt in-place modification even if the size were unchanged.  Instead, one usually writes a modified version of the original file, and upon successfully completing the whole file, one replaces the original with the new.

Comment: What is the required output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need the `if` conditions in the file as a single line that `if` condition is not spreaded as many lines.

Comment: `re.sub(r'^\s*if\s*\(.*?{', lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]\s*', ' ', x.group()), s, flags=re.S|re.M)`? See https://ideone.com/ls79mb

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Super. thanks. It works as expected. Could you please write it to answers with small explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'^\s*if\s*\(.*?{', lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]\s*', ' ', x.group()), s, flags=re.S|re.M)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ls79mb) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tj6U3q/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M` flag)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `if` - an `if` word
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible (due to `re.S`, `.` matches any char)
- `{` - a `{` char.

The match is passed to the lambda expression, `x` is a `MatchData` object. `re.sub(r'[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]\s*', ' ', x.group())` replaces with a space the following substrings:

- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ chars other than non-whitespace, CR and LF (matches "horizontal" whitespaces)
- `[\r\n]`  - a line break char
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tj6U3q/2).

Comment: in the regex if I omit this `^` what it would mean ?

Comment: You will match at any location on a line.

Comment: but `^` shall match even if the line starts with several space and `if` right ?

Comment: `\s*` will match the whitespace.

Comment: actually this question I have asked because of my other question over here. which is  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277811/how-to-use-multi-line-dotall-with-charater-exception-in-python`